# C# NUnit Tests ConfigureTestServices is not injecting service overrides

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, nunit

I'm running into a very strange issue where service overrides are not getting performed in my unit tests.  I'm currently on dotnet 5 and EF Core 5.

This is the code that is used to inject mock overrides for some test services that need to be overwritten:

```
        // Create our test app
        Factory = new WebApplicationFactory<MySolution.Program>()
            .WithWebHostBuilder(builder =>
            {
                builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
                {
                    services.AddScoped<IHttpContextAccessor, TestUser>();
                    services.AddScoped<ITenantStore, TestTenantStore>();
                    services.AddScoped<ITenantProviderService, TestTenantProvider>();
                });

                // Use what is specified on command line, or default to Integration
                string environment = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") ?? "Testing";
                TestContext.Progress.WriteLine($"Running main application with environment {environment}.");
                builder.UseEnvironment(environment);
            });

        var thisFails = Global.Factory.Server.Host.Services.GetRequiredService<ITenantStore>();
```

The `thisFails` variable assignment immediately fails with the following exception when I attempt startup:  `OneTimeSetUp: System.InvalidOperationException : Cannot resolve scoped service 'MySolution.Services.ITenantStore' from root provider.`.

I have no idea why it can't resolve the service as it was clearly added in the test services override.  It also is present in our Startup.cs file, so even if it is not resolving to the overridden service I still would expect it to find the production implementation.  The code had been working previously (without the thisFails assignment) for multiple months. Has anyone else encountered something similar?

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED: I had a forgotten environment variable force setting the ASP environment to "Development", which was overwriting the fallback of "Testing".  After removing the environment variable everything works as expected.